# Making a search engine using Google to show search results from selected websites

Tags: perl, search, search-engine

I want to make a search engine which will use Google to search all the results but the difference will be that it will show results only from the websites which I select i.e. the search results will be from the selected websites whom I approve (putting approved URLs in a file and then using Google to search results from those websites).

How can I do this? I know Perl(beginner level) and HTML. How should I start working on it? Which things I must learn to achieve this goal? I need to know the procedure then I will do that task. Please let me know a good and efficient way to do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/).

Comment: The programming interface for this is documented at http://code.google.com/more/#google-search. Any older APIs are dead or deprecated.

Comment: @Vladimir: Thanks. Can I use this in my website? What are their privacy policies? Can I modify it or not?

Comment: Yes, you can use it on your website using their API. Please see details here - http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/